# PDFTron XOD Viewer not loading on ASP.NET Core MVC 6 Razor View

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, pdftron

PDFTron XOD Viewer not loading XOD File on ASP.NET Core MVC 6 Razor View. Checking the browser console displays error : "Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback: TypeError: Unable to get property 'files' of undefined or null reference".

The browser displays message : "Please" in place of the WebViewer control. I see that this comes from PDFTron WebViewer.js file from the code section as below:

```
else {
            var supportErrorArray = new Array();
            supportErrorArray.push("Please");
            if (allowHTML5) {
                supportErrorArray.push("use an HTML5 compatible browser");
                if (allowSilverlight || allowFlash) {
                    supportErrorArray.push("or");
                }
```

`me.selectedType is none` from `WebVeiwer.js` when I put an alert in the `WebViewer.js` file. **Doesn't PDFTron XODViewer support ASP.NET Core MVC 6?**

I used the a workaround to correct the `WebViewer.js` script by checking :

```
if(me.selectedType == null)
{
     if (this.options.html5Options) {
                $.extend(this.options, this.options.html5Options);
            }
            me._createHTML5();
}
```

MVC 6 Razor View (Document/Index.cshtml) markup is as below:-

```
@model XODViewer.Models.Document

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Document";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/lib/WebViewer.js")"></script>
<style>
    #viewer {
        width: 1024px;
        height: 600px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(function () {
            var docName = '@Html.Raw(Model.DocumentName)';
            var viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer');
            var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
                path: '../../lib',
                type: '../../lib/html5',
                documentType: "xod",
                initialDoc: "../../XodFiles/GettingStarted.xod",
                config: '',
                streaming: false,
                enableAnnotations: false,
                enableOfflineMode: false,
                enableReadOnlyMode: true
            }, viewerElement);
        });
</script>

@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Message)

<div id="viewer" style="padding:10px; word-wrap:break-word;">
</div>
```

ASP.NET Core MVC 6 solution looks as in the attached screenshot.
[image]

I have already setup the content type for XOD as follows:-

```
// Set up custom content types -associating file extension to MIME type
            var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            // Add new mappings
            provider.Mappings[".json"] = "application/json";
            provider.Mappings[".woff"] = "application/font-woff";
            provider.Mappings[".res"] = "text/plain";
            provider.Mappings[".nmf"] = "text/plain";
            provider.Mappings[".pexe"] = "text/plain";
            provider.Mappings[".mem"] = "text/plain";
            provider.Mappings[".brotli"] = "text/plain";
            provider.Mappings[".xod"] = "application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument";
            // Remove MP4 videos.
            //provider.Mappings.Remove(".mp4");

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot", "XodFiles")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/XodFiles"),
                ContentTypeProvider = provider
            });
```

Finally, on running the solution, XOD Viewer or the XOD document is not displayed. Screenshot of the solution running the page and browser console are as shown below.
[image]

Comment: For the 404 error for "localhost/lib/webviewer.js" in the last image, Is the "lib" folder actually a hosted path? If you put say an image in the "lib" folder, can you load into your webpage using "/lib/myimage.png"? If you get a 404 with that, than your path would appear to be wrong.

Comment: 'lib' is a hosted folder. I have put an image in the 'lib' folder and was able to open it. Even I was able to open 'WebViewer.js' file from browser.

Comment: I'm confused about the "Please" part. Is the text "Please" appearing? If you are getting a 404 for WebViewer.js than I don't see how any of its code would be triggered. Finally, from the code you posted, that is an old version of WebViewer (from circa 2013). Please update to WebViewer 2.2.2.

Comment: @Ryan : Resolved after upgrading to V2.2.2. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved after upgrading to WebViewer V2.2.2 as suggested by Ryan.